# Getting bogus recovery phone number changed emails at my recovery email for accounts that aren't mine

Tags: gmail, security, google-account

Recently I've been getting a lot of emails sent to my backup email address alerting me that the recovery phone number for my Gmail account has changed, but the account referenced in the email is not mine. I am receiving these emails for multiple different Gmail addresses. As best as I can tell, it's a legitimate email from Google (I've examined the HTML source, the links lead to the same place as legitimate Google emails I generate would lead to).

It appears as though somebody is registering Gmail accounts and using my non-Gmail email address as the backup email, but I cannot figure out what they are attempting to accomplish. It does not appear to be a case of somebody with a similar name mistakenly entering my address because the names on the Gmail accounts are very different both from my name and from each other, and look like the sorts of names that a real person would create (e.g. `elizabethkerr2342@gmail.com`). Has anyone else seen this happening, or have any idea what the perpetrators are trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to phish you. I'd mark it as spam/phishing and move on

Comment: @Sathya That's what I figure, but I'm trying to figure out what the end goal is. At most I'd be confirming that the recovery email address exists, and that someone is monitoring it. They don't have my gmail address or phone number though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest contacting Google Support more than likely someone either entered the wrong address for their account recovery information or they're Phishing.  You can contact google through their [contact page](http://www.google.com/contact/).  Either way Google's support teams are usually very helpful at getting these issues sorted.